# JS is not rendered in Liquid section

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I have started working on Liquid a couple of weeks ago.

Either I write

```
popup-navigation.liquid

{% javascript %}
    console.log("coucou")
    console.log("{{ section.settings.type }}")
{% endjavascript %}
<div class="popup-navigation js-popup-navigation" data-popup-content>
    <div id="popup-navigation-home">
        <div style="height: 50px" class="popup-navigation__head pt-20 pb-10 px-10 d-lg-none">
            <div class="container">
```

or

```
popup-navigation.liquid

<script>
    console.log("coucou")
    console.log("{{ section.settings.type }}")
</script>
<div class="popup-navigation js-popup-navigation" data-popup-content>
    <div id="popup-navigation-home">
        <div style="height: 50px" class="popup-navigation__head pt-20 pb-10 px-10 d-lg-none">
            <div class="container">
```

doesn't log in the console.

How should I correct this?

Thank you !

Comment: The second one is correct. You can check the HTML of the page returned by the server to see what's the problem.

Comment: OK. so whats up with the docs: https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/sections/section-assets#javascript

Comment: written code into this tag `{% javascript %}` is collected and compiled into a separate file while page code is rendered,and simple `<script>`  tag inline the code into page.